# linux kernel newer then 4.3.x is not supported installing ovs from shell script ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, kernel

i am installing openvswitch from the shell file using openvswitch.tar

shell file :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
apt-get install -y git python-simplejson python-qt4 python-twisted-conch automake autoconf gcc uml-utilities libtool build-essential git pkg-config linux-headers-`uname -r`
tar -zxvf openvswitch-2.5.5.tar.gz
cd openvswitch-2.5.5
./boot.sh 
./configure --with-linux=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build 
make && make install 
cd datapath/linux 
modprobe openvswitch 
lsmod | grep openvswitch
touch /usr/local/etc/ovs-vswitchd.conf 
mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/openvswitch 
cd ../.. 
ovsdb-tool create /usr/local/etc/openvswitch/conf.db   
vswitchd/vswitch.ovsschema 
ovsdb-server /usr/local/etc/openvswitch/conf.db \ 
--remote=punix:/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock \ 
--remote=db:Open_vSwitch,Open_vSwitch,manager_options \ 
--private-key=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,private_key \ 
--certificate=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,certificate \ 
--bootstrap-ca-cert=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,ca_cert --pidfile  
--detach --log-file 
ovs-vsctl --no-wait init 
ovs-vswitchd --pidfile --detach 
ovs-vsctl show 
ovs-vsctl --version 
ps -ea | grep ovs
```

Error from this shell file is

```
configure: error: Linux kernel in /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic/build is version 4.15.18, but version newer than 4.3.x is not supported (please refer to the FAQ for advice)
```

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop. 
  openvswitch version 2.5.5

.tar release 2.5.5

every thing else is running file in the shell file

Comment: Please refer to the faq it says. So what does that say?

Comment: sorry for late reply. in FAQ they have discussed about openvswitch. according to the FAQ the problem is with the openvswitch and linux kernel release.  openvswitch version 2.5.5 is not supported by linux 4.15 kernel. 
how can i upgrade to new openvswitch version?
Below link is detail of ovs version and linux kernels 
http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/faq/releases/

Comment: the answer to this question in FAQ is :
You have the following options:
   - Use the Linux kernel module supplied with the kernel that you are using.
- If there is a newer released version of Open vSwitch, consider building that one, because it may support the kernel that you are building against.
- The Open vSwitch "master" branch may support the kernel that you are using, so consider building the kernel module from "master".